# Session in MVC 3 for storing text in a textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to programming, especially to MVC. I have designed a blog in MVC 3 ASP.NET for a client. The blog also have user account for admin for content management.

Once logged in, Admin can create new post. Sometimes the post can be long text. Therefore, I want to create a session to temporarily save the content within the text box as the user types it in automatically. Once the user click the submit button, the sessions ends and the text will be permanently saved.

This allows the users to leave the post half way through, come back and carry on from where they left. Also, if the browser close accidently, the user does not loose the text already typed in.

I have been trying find tutorial on this, but was unable to find a useful tutorial so far.

Any help, or point to useful tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need some sort of autosave feature. One option is the Sisyphus.js jQuery Autosave plugin that saves the form state in LocalStorage. No changes to your server side ocde is needed, so it should work for any existing ASP.NET MVC application.

https://github.com/simsalabim/sisyphus

Comment: Thank you. where do you initiate the jQuery? In the Layout.cshtml or in the Controller? I know it's a stupid question, but I am new to MVC

Comment: All jquery is handled in the view since it is client side.